# Selenium PHPunit fireEvent - "You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments."

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-ide

I'm trying to write an automation suite for a Magento site, and am running into a roadblock when trying to click a Buy Now button.

The button code looks like:

```
<button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
```

so apparently the javascript onclick means that the regular `$this->click()` approach won't work, and I need to use `fireEvent()`. The problem is that it always fails with
"You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments."

I've tried calling it in a number of different ways, including using the code direct from selenium IDE exported as phpunit test case.

```
$this->fireEvent('button','click');
$this->fireEvent('//button[@type='button']','click');
```

Code examples I've found online suggest the first should work:
https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/SeleniumTestCaseTest.php

I see there samples like  `$this->fireEvent('theTextbox', 'blur');`

I'm out of options, so hoping someone has hit and fixed this before.

Comment: The problem what I see from your code with brackets. Try something like this - `$this->fireEvent("//button[@type='button']",'click');` with double brackets.

Comment: Hi, I think you are referring to the single quotes vs double quote " and ' ?

Comment: Could you paste your real code where you firing the event with button? Because that part of code which you wrote before has a problems with quotes (not braces, my misspelling ). You should use or double quote or make proper escaping for single quote near @type='button', use `@type=\'button\'` instead

Comment: Hi, I think you are referring to the single quotes vs double quote " and ' ? The code is like this, which looks ok to me? `$this->fireEvent("//button[@type='button']","click");` It was my mistake typing out the code here, but the code above that I pasted in is ok I think, and fails with the same error.

Comment: I tried a different approach, using selenium IDE, I set up a step with command as fireEvent, target as css=button[type="button"] and value as click. If I run this in the IDE, the click takes. However, if I export it, the resulting code `$this->fireEvent("css=button[type=\"button\"]", "click");` generates the same failure.

Comment: Last comment - the code that throws the exception is: `private function checkArguments($arguments)
    {
        if (count($arguments) > 1) {
            throw new Exception('You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments.');
        }
    }` - this is in phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/CommandsHolder.php. It's clearly expecting one argument, where the function spec says it takes two. I'm lost.